# Unable to select element by xpath from dropdown menu with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu

I'm having a hard time trying to select an element from a dropdown menu with Selenium.

Inspecting the page it looks like this:

```
<select id="numbers" name="numbers" style="display: inline-block;">
<option value="all">all numbers</option>
<option value="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b">One</option>
<option value="c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c">Two</option>
<option value="34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f">Three</option>
</select>
```

The code I'm using is:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="numbers"]/option[3]'))
)

element.click();
```

But I'm receiving the error:

```
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="numbers"]/option[3]'))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/7q/ttwklc8j10x_8q7yy8t2scpw0000gn/T/tmpYJKH0R/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///var/folders/7q/ttwklc8j10x_8q7yy8t2scpw0000gn/T/tmpYJKH0R/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/7q/ttwklc8j10x_8q7yy8t2scpw0000gn/T/tmpYJKH0R/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/7q/ttwklc8j10x_8q7yy8t2scpw0000gn/T/tmpYJKH0R/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/7q/ttwklc8j10x_8q7yy8t2scpw0000gn/T/tmpYJKH0R/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

For what I'm able to understand it's failing to locate the xpath, even if i double-checked copy/pasting it from Chrome.

What am I missing? Thank you for your help.

Comment: try using cssSelector `select#numbers option:nth-child(3)`

Answer (score 1):

As, you have to select option from **Select** control, it is better to use Select class as shown below:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("numbers"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Two")
```

Let me know, whether above code works for you.

Comment: I agree that this is the best way to deal with SELECT elements but I'm guessing there is something else going on here like the element is in an IFRAME or is not visible, etc. It will need some more investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to click on that drop-down menu, than options will get displayed.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="numbers"]')))
element.click();
```

and than perform click on `//option[3]`